# drupal modules configuration page not loading displaying nothing

Tags: drupal, configuration, module

I have placed my Drupal site on another domain in a subfolder (www.abc.com/abc).
Issue is that modules configuration page is not loading any content.

What I have done so far is the following:

1. Increase memory limit to 512
2. Increase execution time to 5000
3. Increase fetch time to 5000

What am I going wrong? How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Check the error log and post here the output. That should give some hints on what's going on. Also post information about your setup - which version of Drupal, what modules are installed etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check error by adding two lines in settings.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Then take next action according to errors.

Comment: Are able to get any warning:

Comment: You can disable some of the recently installed module from system table by making status 0. and try reload page.

Comment: still not able to get anything what if i have some modules not uploaded  at server but exist in DB in system table

Comment: don't warry about that it if module files will not there then drupal will ingnore that module.

Comment: no devang, i can provide url but offcourse not login credentials because its company property

Comment: url www.pbcaptain.co.uk/paintballgames